# Is there a way to tell if a device supports Power Delivery (PD) via Thunderbolt?

Tags: laptop, thunderbolt

My laptop is an EVGA SC15 and has a Thunderbolt 3 port on it, but no where can I find if it supports Power Delivery for charging the laptop. Is there a way to see if it does?

[Thunderbolt website for the laptop](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/product/evga-sc15-geforce-gtx-1060-gaming-laptop)

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't mention Thunderbolt in the spec breakdown ... at https://www.evga.com/articles/01113/evga-sc15-g-sync-gaming-laptop/

Comment: Yeah, that website is garbage. It does have the thunderbolt insignia on the top of the website but I can't find anything else about it besides the website I linked in my original post.